# What is the difference between "bundle exec rake" and "bundle exec rackup" and where does the flow of execution start for rackup?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I understand that "bundle exec" is directing the bundler to execute something in the context of the given directory and gemfile.

But what is the difference between `bundle exec rake` and `bundle exec rackup`?

Also, in the case of `bundle exec rackup` what is the start of flow of execution?

Answer (score 2):

They are different tools.

- [`rake`](https://github.com/ruby/rake) runs task scripts defined using a special DSL.
- [`rackup`](https://github.com/rack/rack#label-rackup) is a part of [`rack`](https://github.com/rack/rack) which is a minimal webserver interface.

> rackup is a useful tool for running Rack applications, which uses the Rack::Builder DSL to configure middleware and build up applications easily.
> rackup automatically figures out the environment it is run in, and runs your application as FastCGI, CGI, or WEBrick—all from the same configuration.

To run a Rack application you can pass a path to it as a parameter:
`bundle exec rackup yourapp.ru`
Or create `config.ru` file with your application initialization and just run `bundle exec rackup`.

Here is the minimal Rack application:

```rb
run ->(env) { [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html'}, ['Hi Mugen']] }
```

**UPD**

As @tadman mentioned in a comment below `bundle exec` just loads what's in the `Gemfile` and prepared the environment. Also, dependent on your setup you can run `rake` and `rackup` without the `bundle exec` command.

Answer (score 2):

I see four overlapping questions here:

- **What is `bundle exec <whatever>`?**

  - ...it is comparable to:

    - `/usr/bin/<whatever>` ...or...
    - `/usr/bin/env <whatever>`
  - `exec` is a keyword for bundle and understood by it
  - the `<whatever>` following that `bundle exec` is just a name
  - `bundle exec` prepares something and then tries to run `<whatever>`
- **What do `rake` and `rackup` have in common?**

  - they are two unrelated tools which happen to be programmed in Ruby
  - they can both be installed in the standard Ruby eco-system...
  - ...and thus be launched via `bundle exec ...`
- **What does `rake` do?**

  - it is a tool like `make`
  - it can be made to e.g. launch a C compiler to compile some code
  - ...and like `make` it gets its instructions from a file written in a rake-specific language
- **What does `rackup` do?**

  - it launches a (preinstalled) webserver with a specific configuration

    - ...which will lead to simple Ruby methods being called on each HTTP request
  - it relies on...

    - an installed webserver (one out of a pool of supported servers) to handle HTTP
    - `rack`, to turn

      - interpreted requests into simple method calls ...and...
      - return values into proper responses which the webserver understands
  - if called without arguments

    - it will use the file `config.ru` from the current working directory
    - ...and use the contained `rack`-conforming Ruby code to serve requests